# SignUp with other emails in Entra ID B2C with Razorpage WebApp

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, razor-pages

I have created a SignIn and SignUp user flow in Entra ID that allows emails and accounts from AzureAD and Microsoft respectively. This flow is triggered by a Razorpage WebApp.

[Identityprovider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3j8H.png)

I want users to be able to sign up with other emails, such as XY@web.de. How can I achieve this?

Details:

The current SignUp flow only allows emails from AzureAD and Microsoft.
I would like users to be able to register with other emails as well, e.g. XY@web.de.
The registration is done via a Razorpage WebApp:

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseRewriter(
    new RewriteOptions().Add(
        context =>
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignedOut")
            { context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/"); };


        })

);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

[Model for register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k087t.png)

[login mask 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbM6E.png)

[login mask 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYU71.png)

Error in english: "XXXX@web.de" cannot be used at this time because this username does not belong to any Azure AD organization. Try using a different username

Greetings

Comment: What is the framework and version of your app?

Comment: @Harshitha net6.0 is the target framework.

Comment: Can you please share the screen cap of the login form.

Comment: @Harshitha I added a picture above. "Model for register". 
How does this help? I think the service can't handle custom emails.

Comment: Have you tried with Signupsignin single option.

Comment: Where can I find it?

Comment: Check in the azure ad b2c user flows

Comment: I have asked the screencap for login form not the code.

Comment: @Harshitha I added the login form above :)